# How to run multiple "Applications" under one compoundJS instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, compoundjs

I've been using nodeJS + expressJS for several years now developing a custom Application Platform for our organization.  Our central framework provides a common set of services (authentication, language, administration, etc...) for any installed Modules/Applications under it.

I would like to switch our framework out with compoundJS.  However I'm not familiar with the design constraints imposed by it (and Rails apps in general)  and can't seem to figure out how to accomplish what I'm after.

- I would like to only have a single server instance running:  all
  requests first process through our common authentication checking. 
  Then are passed on to an application's controllers.
- I would also like to have each application separated out:  preferably
  under a separate site/applications/ directory.   Each of these
  applications could be designed using compoundJS normally.  And I would like to install them like:

  ```
  cd site/applications
  npm install site-hr
  npm install site-finance
  npm install site-payroll
  ```

  this would then have all the routes from /hr,  /finance,  /payroll operational.

How do I accomplish this?

Is there a way to get compoundJS to search the nonstandard  /applications/* folders for models/controllers/views and load them while keeping the central /site configurations?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Why change after several years?

Comment: Good Question.  We'd like to use off the shelf technologies when we can, and I'd like to take advantage of the Model, Controllers and generators of commonJS.  When we started there weren't many MVC frameworks out for node.  Right now our team has the time to explore these new ones and incorporate them into our stack.  Hopefully we will reduce the code we are trying to maintain by using commonJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I needed something similar: I needed to put together tool applications in a portal.

I found a way to include child applications in a parent's Compound application as node modules. I wrote a guide on how to do it and sent a pull request to add it in the advanced folder of [CompoundJS' guides](https://github.com/compoundjs/guides). It is also available [here](https://github.com/RaphaelRheault/guides/blob/master/advanced/multiple-application-integration.md). It requires a bit of work, but it works fine with 4 applications for us.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks!  This will definitely get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just use `app.use` in config/environment.js to map your sub-apps:

```
var mod = require('your-compound-module');
app.use('/subroot', mod());
```

When you visit /subroot/any-path, then it will be handled by /anypath route of your sub-app. Note, that you don't need any additional work on path helpers, as they will start with '/subroot' automatically (handled on compound side).

Comment: So is there some documentation on how to setup 'your-comound-module' so all my routes, models, views and controllers are properly found and usable?

Comment: Just follow usual pattern created by generator: module should export single method instantiating your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good point, but we haven't seen any implementation yet. May be years later there would be some.

Using a proxy layer in front of the instances would be a general method, usually with Nginx, Vanish Cache etc. For the bleeding edge techs, I've heard [**Phusion Passenger**](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) has [implemented Node.js support](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Node.js), but I haven't successfully tested yet. If you are familiar with Ruby, it would be a good try.

If you really want to construct a big project with many modules, you can try out some industrialized frameworks for instance [**Architect**](https://github.com/c9/architect) for [Cloud9 IDE](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) project.

For authentication, I think it's necessary to use independent methods in each application, but they can share with one user database.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I wrote "commonJS" instead of compoundJS.  But I did like the looks of Architect.  I think I could use that in our framework as well.  Thanks!